# Lemma of Whitehead

Tags: analysis, algebraic-topology, definition, homotopy-theory

this is the lemma of Whitehead 
[image]

And i really don't understand the proof 
[image]

How to see that $k$ is well defined (i.e how to write an element from $X\cup_{\varphi_i}e^{\lambda} , i=0,1$ )

and how to write $l$ ?

Please

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at the cited paper?

Comment: this :http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/jhcw3.pdf

Comment: i don't understand it ,it's so difficult for me >_<

Comment: The space $X\cup_{\phi_i} e^\lambda$ is the quotient space of the disjoint union of $X$ and $e^\lambda$ formed using the equivalence relation $x\sim e$ if $e$ is in the boundary of the cell $e^\lambda$ and $\phi_i (e) = x$.  So to check that $k$ is well-defined you just need to show that it respects these identifications.  Incidentally, this is a page from Milnor's Morse Theory book, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @DanRamras yes this page is from the book of Milnor ,Morse theory . please tell me how to write l , please thank you